# where to put css reset in react project dir

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app

Looking to start a create-react-app (in vscode). I'd like to start clean using some basic css reset code.

Question: 
  Where's the best place to drop css reset in the project?

```
option a) in the `index.css` file auto generated via `create-react-app`

option b) in the `App.css` file auto generated via `create-react-app`

option c) any other best practice and/or recommendation
```

To clarify, `index.css` and `App.css` by default are located in the same directory.

and..

`App.js` is rooted in `index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

docs say place reset in `index.css`. I just want to be sure that `index.css` 'cascades' properly down to `App.css` given this structure.

Comment: In my opinion, you're overthinking it. option a and b are valid. You can also create a separate css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic css reset can be inside index.css. This will overwrite all default browse styles as index .html is the entry point file. Then the css you write in each component will cascade on top of this style.

In the end as the cascading effect, you are overriding default browser styles and adds your component styles.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the official Create-React-App docs recommend https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-css-reset/

> This project setup uses PostCSS Normalize for adding a CSS Reset.
>
> To start using it, add @import-normalize; anywhere in your CSS file(s).
> You only need to include it once and duplicate imports are automatically
> removed. Since you only need to include it once, a good place to add it
> is index.css or App.css.

```
#index.css
@import-normalize; /* bring in normalize.css styles */
/* rest of app styles */
```

> You can control which parts of normalize.css to use via your project's browserslist.

Looks like Option B would be the best route to take.

Answer (score 0):

In my react app I usually maintain a theme folder and a file named global-styles.css. I use the file app/theme/global-styles.css for global / css reset code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all CSS in the Index.css file and add
`@import-normalize;`

It Basically reset all your CSS which is applied by the browser!